# Create a glass-looking shape with python console in Blender

Tags: python, materials, transparency, glass

I am trying to create in Blender a 3D model representing some optical scheme. I managed to create elements looking like pieces of glass using the Blender GUI, but cannot repeat this using python console in Blender. I use this code to create a rectangular object.

```
import bpy
verts6 = [(-5,-5,0),(-5,-5,10),(0,-5,10),(0,-5,0),(-5,-4.7,0), (-5,-4.7,10),(0,-4.7,10),(0,-4.7,0)]
faces6 = [(0,1,2,3),(4,5,6,7),(0,4,5,1),(2,6,7,3),(1,5,6,2),(0,4,7,3)]
mymesh6 = bpy.data.meshes.new("HP2")
myobject6 = bpy.data.objects.new("HP2", mymesh6)
myobject6.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(myobject6)
mymesh6.from_pydata(verts6,[],faces6)
mymesh6.update(calc_edges=True)
```

Then i change manually material of this object to the same material of the manually created objects. It is "Glass BSDF". However, instead of transparent piece of glass i get some reflective surface.

[image: 3D view]
[image: render]

Numbers in these figures: 1 is the python created object 2 is the embedded object

I want 1 to look like 2. What is wrong? They look different even in the 3D viewer.

**Solution:**

[thibsert](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55910/thibsert) found the explanation - "the normals must be recalculated". I've added the following lines at the end and it worked.

```
import bmesh
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mymesh6)
bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals(bm, faces=bm.faces)
bm.to_mesh(mymesh6)
bm.clear()
mymesh6.update()
bm.free()
```

Comment: The object generated by your script has no consistent normals (some point inside, some outside). That why it looks different in 3d view, and why the shader is wrong. Recalculate the normals (Ctrl-N) to fix the problem (it can be done via script).

Comment: Awesome! it worked, updated the question with solution. Thanks thibsert!

Comment: @thibsert Could you add this as an answer, please?